# Failed at the bitcore-node@3.1.3

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

## Approach

I'm trying to install [bitcore](https://bitcore.io/) on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18 but I could not.

## Problem

I have followed the following steps:

```
# Install NVM (1)
#  Install script
#   With CURl
# curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
#       or Wget:
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

Adds the source line to your profile (~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile, or ~/.bashrc)

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm

# Install Node.js v4 LTS
nvm install v4
# Install ZeroMQ and Tools
apt-get install libzmq3-dev build-essential
# Install Bitcore
npm install -g bitcore
```

> More information

[Bitcore Full](https://bitcore.io/guides/full-node/)

[NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)

But when I run it I get the following errors

> ## Error in Windows con git

```
$ npm install -g bitcore
```

Output

```
> bitcore-node@3.1.3 preinstall C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\bitcore-node
> ./scripts/download

"." no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\utf-8-validate\node_modules'
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bitcore\node_modules\utf-8-validate\node_modules'
npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat \'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\bitcore\\node_modules\\utf-8-validate\\node_modules\'',
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'lstat',
npm WARN   path: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\bitcore\\node_modules\\utf-8-validate\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bitcore-node@3.1.3 preinstall: `./scripts/download`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bitcore-node@3.1.3 preinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-24T12_23_42_800Z-debug.log
```

> ## Error in Ubuntu

```
npm install -g bitcore
```

Output

```
> bitcore-node@3.1.3 preinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.9.1/lib/node_modules/bitcore/node_modules/bitcore-node
> ./scripts/download

./scripts/download: line 30: cd: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.9.1/lib/node_modules/bitcore/node_modules/bitcore-node/scripts/../bin: Permission denied
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-22-generic
npm ERR! argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.9.1/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.9.1/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bitcore"
npm ERR! node v4.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bitcore-node@3.1.3 preinstall: `./scripts/download`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bitcore-node@3.1.3 preinstall script './scripts/download'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bitcore-node package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./scripts/download
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bitcore-node
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bitcore-node
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
```

## Question

Someone who has executed it sees an erroneous step or the same thing happens to him and he has solved it.

Thank you !!

Comment: can you add /root/npm-debug.log content?

Comment: @Adam Go¡¡ An moment

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zBPT2iKD This is an part

Comment: "bitcore" is dead, regardless. It's not Bitcoin Core, to ease confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

> "bitcore" is dead, regardless. It's not Bitcoin Core, to ease
>   confusion.